# How can I use wait-for with nestjs and docker

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I am trying to run a nestjs app that runs on postgres db via typeorm, on docker toolbox. I need to make the backend server wait for the database configurations to finish and open the port so I tried out wait-for shell script. However, its not running and docker logs on backend server container is showing

```
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
sh: 1: ./bin/wait-for.sh: not found
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgresdb:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment: 
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'admin'
        POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_DB: 'yourcarprod'
        PGDATA: '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata'
    ports: 
        -   '5432:5432'
    networks: 
      - shared-network
    volumes:
      - db-config:/etc/postgresql
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./backend/src/database/backup:/data_backup/data/pgdata

  backend-app:
    container_name: nestjs_api_prod
    image: nestjs-api-image
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    command: sh -c './bin/wait-for.sh -t 0 postgresdb:5432 -- yarn start:prod'
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - shared-network

networks:
  shared-network:
      
volumes:
  db-config:
  db-data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN yarn global add @nestjs/cli
RUN yarn global add ts-node
RUN yarn global add typeorm
RUN yarn install 

RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat

COPY . .

RUN yarn build 

CMD ["sh", "-c", "yarn run migration:generate && yarn start:prod"]
```

**modifications in package.json:**

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/main",
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
    "migration:generate": "yarn run build && yarn typeorm migration:generate -n CreatedDatabase"
  }
...
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

I am a novice in docker and don't have much or almost any knowledge in shell scripting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sanity check: does the `wait-for.sh` have DOS or Unix line endings?  If it has DOS line endings then you can get something like this "not found" error.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems to have worked after using dos2unix command on the wait-for.sh file :)